# Tiva-C Launchpad - Sending a Tx signal over long distance

Tags: microcontroller

I have a 5v square wave signal being sent from a microcontroller at a baud rate of 115200.  I would like to send this signal over longer distances, say 15+ feet.  What is the best/simplest approach to ensure this signal is sent cleanly over the longer distance?

Comment: Try to provide some more specs. What kind of voltage levels, frequencies, accuracy, ... are we talking about? If it's kbits/second, any old wire will do. If you are pushing it to megabaud, you might need to look at differential/matched impedance/... and going into multiple megabauds to gigabauds, you are going to really need drivers, filters, perhaps look at something like preemphasis/...

Answer (score 3):

Consider using RS485 drivers and receivers and a properly terminated twisted pair. The old [SN75176](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65176b.pdf) is one choice- there are newer products.

Assuming you're talking about a unidirectional one-wire type interface, you can use a single pair from Ethernet cable, for example. You can use some or all the other wires for the (required) ground.

You would need a transceiver at each end (you can enable both continuously) and a suitable termination resistor at each end - for CAT5 100 ohm resistors would be better than the usual 120 ohms used for RS485.

Using the above arrangement, a few hundred feet should be no problem.

The 75176 will work with a 0/3.3V input signal from the Tiva so you don't need a voltage translator.